# What exactly is the throughput restriction on an entity group in Google App Engine's datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The documentation describes a limitation on the throughput to an entity group in the datastore, but is vague on what exactly the limitation is. My confusion is in two parts:

**1. What is being restricted?**

Specifically, is it:

1. The number of writes?
2. Number of transactions that write to the datastore?
3. Number of transactions regardless of whether it reads or writes to the datastore?

**2. What is the type of the restriction?**

Specifically, is it:

1. An artificially enforced one-per-second hard rule?
2. An empirically observed max throughput, that may in practice be better based on factors like network load, etc.?

Comment: Hey there. This is not an perfect and direct answer, and you may well have seen it before. It states that the limit comes from the Megastore layer. It also talks about using aggregations to achieve up to 300 writes per second.  https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/fast-and-reliable-ranking-in-datastore/

Comment: Thanks! Yes I had come across this article. I've understood that aggregating writes into a transaction gives me more throughput. So the answer to "What is restricted" is either 2 or 3. But I have not come across anything that definitive that resolves the which of those it actually is.

Answer (score 4):

There's no throughput restriction per se, but to guarantee atomicity in transactions, updates must be serialized and applied sequentially and in order, so if you make enough of them things will start to fail/timeout. This is called [datastore contention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention):

> Datastore contention occurs when a single entity or entity group is updated too rapidly. The datastore will queue concurrent requests to wait their turn. Requests waiting in the queue past the timeout period will throw a concurrency exception. If you're expecting to update a single entity or write to an entity group more than several times per second, it's best to re-work your design early-on to avoid possible contention once your application is deployed.

To directly answer your question in simple terms, it's specifically the number of writes per entity group (5/ish per second), and it's just a rule of thumb, your milage may vary (greatly).

Some people have reported no contention at all, while others have problems to get more than 1 update per second. As you can imagine this depends on the complexity of the operation and the load of all the machines involved in execution.

Comment: But it can't be the number of **writes.** Reasoning from the datastore contention perspective, it seems like it must be the number of **transactions** (So multiple writes inside a transaction must be ok). But the workings of the datastore seem complicated and I don't want to trust my understanding of it. And then do transactions which only read from the datastore affect the rate somehow? So many questions, so much vagueness.

Comment: Uhm... there's something you're not understanding but I can't tell what hehe. Reads are not affected by this, when transactional you're guaranteed you'll get a consistent representation of the data (not half-updated). This only affects updates done to an entity group, you can have many short transactions or few long transactions, all that matters is how quickly the entity group can "release the lock". Try to think of how would you implement this, it'll be pretty clear why this "restrictions" come up.

Comment: Ok, so you are definitely wrong about the writes per second. Here is a direct quote from a talk at Google I/O (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO015C3R6dw#t=6m01s).  "If you use batch puts or transactions, those all count as single write, so you can get high entity per second throughput, if you fan in your writes and do them in batches". I think you have an overly simplistic view of how the datastore works. Have you read their paper on megastore, on which the datastore is built (http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36971.html)?

Comment: The throughput limitations arise from the overhead of coordination between distributed data centers, not the size of the transactions...

Comment: You're right in that i'm over simplifying things, we haven't even covered entity group size and tablets, at that point i would recommend reading on how it's actually implemented to understand, but if you have read it already then you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Limits:

- writes per second to an entity group
- entity groups per cross-entity-group transaction (XG transaction)

There is a [limit of 1 write per second per entity group](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency). This is a documented limit that in practice appears to be a 'soft' limit, as in it is possible to exceed it, but not guaranteed to be allowed. Transactions 'block' if the entity had been written to in the last second, however the API allows for transient exceptions to occur as well. Obviously you would be susceptible to timeouts as well.

This does not affect the overall number of transactions for your app, just specifically related to that entity group. If you need to, you can design portions of your data model to get around this limitation.

There is a limit of 25 entity groups per XG transaction, meaning a transaction can not incorporate more than [25 entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Cross_group_transactions) in its context (reads, writes etc). This used to be a limit of 5 but was recently increased.

So to answer your direct questions:

1. Writes for the entire entity group (as defined by the root key) within a second window (which is not strict)
2. artificially enforced one-per-second soft rule

Comment: I'm quite certain that you are wrong about the first point. As I said in the comments to another answer -- Here is a direct quote from a talk at Google I/O (youtube.com/watch?v=xO015C3R6dw#t=6m01s). "If you use batch puts or transactions, those all count as single write, so you can get high entity per second throughput, if you fan in your writes and do them in batches".

Comment: So the answer to "What is restricted" must either be 2 (write transactions) or 3 (write or read transactions). I understand that "writes per second" is littered in the documentation, but the term is used rather loosely as is apparent from the youtube video which makes clear that is not really writes per second. I am trying to tease out the exact meaning.

Comment: Possibly I am. All I have to go by is the official docs and my experience. It may be there is some confusion in terminology between us. Transactions are limited only in writes per entity group, and quantity of entity groups in a XG transaction. I haven't watched the video - I would guess from your description that they're describing using queues (participating in transactions) to fan out writes and thus stop transactions being XG, thus improving overall write entity group throughput.

Comment: The video (at least the part I am talking about) is dealing with writes to a single entity group, so lets leave XG issues aside for now. They say that if you group together writes (to a single entity group) into a single transaction, then it only counts as one write as far as the throughput restriction is concerned. So really they mean to say that the throughput restrictions is on __transactions__ rather than __writes__. You can write 1000 changes to single entity group in a second if you want, as long as it is in a single transaction.

Comment: That is what is meant by the limit of one write per entity group per second. It specifically doesn't mean one entity, it means any number of entities that participate in the same transaction that share the same root key. So to get higher throughput, you can include many entities that share the same root key. If you didn't do it this way, your example could take up to 1000 seconds to write the same 1000 entities.

Comment: I think we are in agreement that the entities have to belong to the same group (have the same root) for any hope of achieving high throughput. What we may not be agreeing on is the following: In order to achieve the high throughput we **also need to make sure that we put the writes into a single transaction**.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the other way around. If each entity is in a separate entity group, and you do not include them in transactions you will get highest throughput. If (for transactional reasons) you need to write them together, and they cannot fit inside the XG limit, then the highest throughput comes from writing as many at once as you can (within datastore RPC limits) in a single transaction. If your concern is high throughput you should design your entities to not need transactions (ie group all data in one entity) and be their own root entity.

Comment: Fair enough. I do need transactional integrity however.

Comment: The question now is if I have 1000 read transactions and 1 write transactions a minute, is this going to run into throughput restrictions? i.e. do read transactions affect write throughput?

Answer (score -6):

If you ask that question, then the Google DataStore is probably not for you.

The Google DataStore is an experimental database, where the API can be changed any time - it is also ment for retail apps, non-critical applications.

A clear indication you meet when you signup for the DataStore, something like no responsibility to backwards compatibility etc. Another indication is the lack of clear examples, the lack of wrappers providing a simple API to implement an access to the DataStore - and the examples on the net being a soup of complicated installations and procedures to make a simple query.

My own conclusion so far after days of research, is Google DataStore is not ready for commercial use, but looks promising once it is finished and in a stable release version.

When you search the net, and look at the few Google examples, if there at all are any - it is about to notice whats not mentioned rather than what is mentioned - which is about nothing is mentioned by Google ..... ;-)  If you look at the vendors "supporting" Google DataStore, they simply link to the Google DataStore site for further information, which mention nothing, so you are in a ring where nothing concrete is mentioned ....