# Does the Google Cloud Datastore create transactions implicitly?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In many databases, when an operation is performed without explicitly starting a transaction, the database creates a new transaction implicitly.

Does the datastore do this?

If it does not, is there any model for reasoning about how the data changes in the absence of transactions? How do puts, fetches, and reads, work outside of transactions?

If it does, is there any characterization for when and how. Does it do it always? What is the scope of the transaction?

Comment: the official docs say transactions are optional.

Comment: do you have any links where it is explicit?

Comment: see the offcial docs on java transactions python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutation (put, delete) of a single entity will always be atomic (succeed entirely or fail entirely). You can think of the single mutation as transactional, even if you did not provide a transaction.

However, if you send multiple mutations in the same non-transactional request, that overall request is not atomic. Each mutation may succeed or fail independently -- one failure will not cause the other mutations to be reverted.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the atomicity of single mutations is documented anywhere?

Comment: I don't think it's currently documented. I'm going to check with our docs team to see if we can get it added.

Comment: Thanks, that would be great. I think the datastore is a terrific product but I seriously cannot get over how bad the documentation is. Things like transactions and atomicity are the absolute fundamentals. There should not be any confusion about what is happening at this level.

Comment: As an aside, will it be possible for you to give some insight into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996704. It is about throughput limitations to the datastore. Basically I want to know if transactions that only read from the datastore contribute to the throughput limit of 5 per second? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Transactions are an optional feature of the Datastore; you're not required to use transactions to perform Datastore operations."

so there are no automatic transactions being opened for you across more than a single entity datastore operation.

a single entity commit will behave the same as a transaction internally. so if you are changing more than one entity or committing it more than once, its as if you open and close a transaction every time.

Comment: It seems like the picture is more complicated than that. This is not from the original documentation but Dan Sanderson Book, Programming Google App Engine with Python (also he works for Google): "When you create, update, or delete a single entity, the change occurs in a transaction."

Comment: yes but i thought you were asking about a transaction covering more than one entity. yes a single entity goes the same route as a transaction.

Comment: ive updated the answer to mention that it applies to more than one entity or datastore operation. on a single entity operation yes it behaves the same as a transaction which covers the single entity operation (put, etc) as internally those are multiple operations (to save in more than one place for redundancy etc)

Comment: Do you know if this is part of the official documentation?

Comment: but what implications does it have? its simply being consistent with the way a commit is applied (optimistic concurrency etc)

Comment: that said, do trust Dan more. The official docs are thin and I only have 3 years experience with datastore.